# Open Camera app installed from a UWP app and capture image

Tags: camera, uwp

Instead of creating a Windows built-in camera UI (CameraCaptureUI) or using a custom MediaCapture control and capture picture I want to open any Camera App downloaded in the device to capture an image and get the result.

I have used

```
string uriToLaunch = "microsoft.windows.camera:";

var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

But this just opens the camera app, I need to get the result file back to the app and save it. 
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using:

```cs
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

just opens the default camera, nothing more, the result is a *boolean* with information if the application has been opened successfully, nothing more.

With [CameraCaptureUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241030) you don't need to create camera - this seems to be designed for the task like you have described. With lines:

```cs
var captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(200, 200); 

var photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

you just launch the camera app and your app waits for the photo, which you can process further/save.

If you don't want to use it or [implement own camera capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera), you can think of sharing a picture taken by other app. This is [described well at app-to-app communication at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/). In this case user will have to click <kbd>Share</kbd> button and choose your app as a target. That will invoke [OnShareTargetActivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.OnShareTargetActivated(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs)) event where you can process the received content.

Comment: Is this JS or C#?/

Comment: @JinsPeter This is C#, but in JS there should be something similar.